# Vb.Net - Iterate through files names in Database and then Download them

Tags: vb.net

Need help, as struggling to write code:

Below function will iterate through database to fetch file name and then download those files if exists. I'm struggling to write the code here "Download Files Code here". Also need it to return ARRAY which should be name of files which have been download in this code.

Can anyone please help.

```
Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal SourcePath As String, ByVal TargetPath As String) As Boolean


    Dim DownloadFile As Boolean = False
    Dim lvar_FileName As String = Nothing
    Dim lvar_FileType As String = Nothing

    Using Conn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
        SQLCommand = New SqlCommand("File_List",Conn)
        SQLCommand.CommandText = "Select File_Name from File_List "
        Try
            Conn Conn.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            reader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                'Code Here
                lvar_FileName = reader(0)

        'Download Files Code here

            End While
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Using

    Return DownloadFile 

End Function
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an array i would return a `List(Of String)` since it can be resized:

```
Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal SourcePath As String, ByVal lvar_TargetPath As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim allFiles As New List(Of String) 
    Using Conn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
        Using SQLCommand = New SqlCommand("Select File_Name from File_List", Conn)
            Try
                Conn.Open()
                Using reader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()
                    While reader.Read()
                        Dim fileName = reader.GetString(0)
                        Dim destPath = Path.Combine(SourcePath, fileName)
                        allFiles.Add(destPath)
                    End While
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' Log exception here, otherwise don't catch it
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return allFiles
End Function
```

Comment: Source Path + File Name needs to be copied to Destination Path + File Name. We don't store Source Path or Destination Path in the FILE TABLE so passing this to the function.

Comment: @ConradJagger: Use `Path.Combine`. I've edited my answer to add an example. However, it's still not clear what to do with `lvar_TargetPath` or what you meant with `Destination Path` in your last comment.